# Multiple functions in a $where clause

Tags: socrata, soda

I am constructing a url for a CMS data query.  I get the following to work just fine:

```
    https://data.cms.gov/resource/din4-7td8.json?$$app_token=REDACTED&$where=(starts_with(nppes_provider_zip,'63703') OR starts_with(nppes_provider_zip,'63701')) AND (hcpcs_code='31623' OR hcpcs_code='31622')
```

When I try to substitute calling multiple hcpcs_code values, I get a query.compiler.malformed error.  The following generates the error:

```
    https://data.cms.gov/resource/din4-7td8.json?$$app_token=REDACTED&$where=(starts_with(nppes_provider_zip,'63703') OR starts_with(nppes_provider_zip,'63701') AND hcpcs_code in('31622','31623'))
```

Is it possible that I am using the in(...) function incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have caught you [on IRC](http://dev.socrata.com/irc.html) after you asked this question, but I'll answer here too.

It looks like you're using an old version of that API endpoint which doesn't support the `IN(...)` function. If you migrate to the new version of that dataset API you'll be able to issue your query:

- http://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/data.cms.gov/5fnr-qp4c
- https://data.cms.gov/resource/5fnr-qp4c.json?$where=(starts_with(nppes_provider_zip,'63703') OR starts_with(nppes_provider_zip,'63701') AND hcpcs_code in('31622','31623'))

Comment: Yes, you did solve my issue on IRC.  Is there another place to look for updated API endpoints regarding government data?  I got the url from the recently added medicare utilization and payment website for the recently added 2013 data.  The endpoint is what is published on the Socrata API section of that data set.

Comment: If you follow the link to the API docs, and you're on the old API (there's basically a shadow copy that is automatically synced to a new dataset/API), you'll be prompted to jump to the new one. There's a walkthrough on what that looks like in the changelog: http://dev.socrata.com/changelog/2015/04/27/new-higher-performance-apis.html